# How an E-mail is sent from your mail SMTP server to others?

Tags: authentication, smtp

Assume you have a Gmail account and want to send an E-mail to an account on yahoo mail server from Gmail account, here are the steps:

1. Client mail manager (say outlook) connects to gmail server and authenticates your account(using username/password that you have already)
2. after the authentication is done, your mail is sent to gmail server

   > so here is the question: how gmail proves itself to yahoo? has
   >   gmail any username/password or some sort of things? is authentication needed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no authentication from one SMTP server to another. The only authentication is from you to gmail.

This is one reason why spam is such a problem. The basic SMTP protocol just assumes there is no spam. You open a connection to a mail server and just send the headers like

```
from: mehrdad@gmail.com
to: gman@yahoo.com

Hello
```

And yahoo.com (the receiver) will happy except the email regardless of what computer it came from.

Because of those issues things have been added but they are optional.

One is [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail). It works by signing your email with a digital signature. The signed email can be verified by the receiver (in your case by yahoo). Yahoo can check for gmail's public key in gmail's DNS records and check that the mail's signature cryptographically matches. It's up to the receiver (yahoo) to decide if it wants to check that or not. If the sender (Google or a spammer) does not add the signature then again, it's up to the receiver to decide what to do with the message. It could assume it's okay and pass it on. It could check if there is a public key available and if it is and the email has no signature then may not pass it on? Or mark it as "possibly spam"

There's also [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework). SPF is designed so that the receiver (yahoo) can verify that only the sender (Google) is allowed to send mail from `gmail.com`.

Then there is [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC). DMARC lets Google (the sender) tell Yahoo (the receiver) what to do when when the stuff above fails. For example wither or not to forward messages who's signatures don't match the key. It's up to the receiver to decide to use this info.

Along with the linked wikipedia articles [here's a pretty good overview of what happens and the problems involved](https://dmarc.org/overview/).